# Is it haram to do height increasing meditation?

Tags: allah

I am 20 years old and only 4ft 10 inch. I am doing a pituitary gland meditation which increases height. Is it something haram?

Comment: If you have a problem with height due to hormonal imbalance then you should see an endocrinologist. They can prescribe treatment and artificial hormones which will be more effective than meditation.

Answer (score 0):

Meditation by itself is not haram as long as it is not related to an other religion. However, this may often be the case if it is not explicitly done in the context of Islam belief.

I personally doubt that meditation can make you grow taller and I suspect that those who promise it want to influence you to practice something that may be haram or just make money.

Comment: It doesn’t include any mantra and other things. It’s like looking into a dot for couple of minutes  with open eyes and then imagine the dot with closed eyes. That's it. I just wanted to make sure if it’s okay.

Comment: Then it is probably not a problem with Islam but I think you should follow the hint of UmH and look for something more serious. You won't grow by looking into a dot.